# How to compare number values with varchar2 containing decimal (both positive and negative) values in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, type-conversion

I'm making a query and one of the tables involved have 2 columns (lat & lng) both are type varchar2 and both have values like 6.22863633 or -75.60202274.
One of the conditions of the query is

```
AND PV.LAT >= '" + lowLat.toString() + "'
AND PV.LAT <= '" + upperLat.toString() + "'";
```

But when lowLat variable have values over 10, there are not results returned despite the fact that there are. If I force the value of the variable under 10, the results are there.

So I can't change the type of the columns because the client forbid the change
I made a query searching for blank spaces and there are a lot of this values with spaces at the end, I try using TRIM and casting with TO_NUMBER but nothing seems to work.

I apreciate any idea on this subjet

Comment: You cannot compare numeric values stored as `VARCHAR2`. It's impossible. Convert to `NUMBER`, then compare, preferably by changing your schema, but otherwise by using `to_number(PV.LAT) between ? and ?`, though that will prevent use of index for improved lookup performance.

Comment: Why are those columns stored as varchars and not numbers in the first place?

Comment: I didn't design the schema, and it belongs to a customer who strictly forbid me to change the type

Comment: I will try the between but the cast To_number seems to fail because of the white spaces characters

Comment: if there's space at the end - trim it first and then cast to number: to_number(trim(column)). If this fails - then please post the errors you get

Comment: Hi, i already try that i don't get any error, just that the query doesn't find data
but if i change the values of the variables to numbers under 9 (they still are in the original interval) then i got data from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thank you for all your ideas, I try everything and manage to get some results, but not the best results, so I convince the costumer to let me create another table to relate the coordinates with the id on the original table on a number format, i will do this tomorrow and change all the related code to work with the new table.
But still thank you a lot, and for me the correct answer was to change the type of the column but ...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** (a little later, but this belongs at the top) - DUH!  what happens if you compare 8 as "between 3 and 15" but AS STRINGS? If you order them as strings, 8 comes after 3 and after 15! You really do need to cast everything as numbers, not as strings. (Besides, if you write it like that, `something between '3' and '15'`, you will not get any rows, ever - because as strings '3' is greater than '15' and Oracle is not flexible in the use of BETWEEN; the lower (smaller) number, date, or string must always come first.)

Original answer:

One way to find out exactly what is stored in the database is to use DUMP. For example:

```
SQL> select dump('   -20.99300') from dual;

DUMP('-20.99300')
--------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=12: 32,32,32,45,50,48,46,57,57,51,48,48
```

By just looking at the output from dump, one can see the value is a VARCHAR2 (Type = 96), it's 12 characters long, the first three are blank spaces (ASCII code 32), etc.

Can you do this... take one of your latitudes that are greater than 10 and call DUMP on it? For example:

```
select dump(max(lat)) from pv
```

and either interpret it for yourself or post it here so we can help you read it.

There is no point in trying to guess at a solution until you (or we) figure out what the problem really is in the first place.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response:

1. the cast is to number
2. This is the output from the dump

`Typ=1 Len=10: 57,46,57,53,56,52,52,56,52,55`

Thank you for your help